# DOM/Page not updating but console.log shows updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing an SPA from scratch and so far I've gotten everything working except the `active` state off the navigation links will not update according to where user is navigating to.

The funny thing is that when I open up the Developer Tools in Chrome, under "Elements" the DOM is still showing the `active` class on the original nav element, but under "Console", when I console.log the element, it shows that the class has been removed.

I've tried `event.stopPropagation()` in a few places and the `jQuery.off()` function but nothing seems to fix this problem.

**Problem:** The class list of the active and the former active link doesn't update when clicking on a navigation link, but the console.log function does show an updated classlist off the former active link

**Desired Behaviour:** That the former active link losses its `active` class and that the currently active link gets an `active` class after its navigation link has been clicked and the page renders the new content(the supposedly new page).

**UPDATE 1:** Updated the code according to suggestions and it got the first part of my problem working. Removing `active` class from all `li` elements now works, but making the page render the updated links with `active` class on currently active link after navigation does not work. See in app.js under generateView() function.

**UPDATE 2:** Got it working. See on the bottom of this Question. Thank you!

My app.js

```
(function ($, hbs){

'use strict';

// declare some usefull variables to use throughout the app
var
    doc = document,
    oldPath = '',
    newPath = '',
    navParentEl = '';


// 1: Manually trigger a hashchange to start the app.
window.onload = function (e) {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
};

// 2: Catch clicks on the root-level element for anchor tag clicks.
doc.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    var tag = e.target;

    // check element clicket
    if (tag.tagName === 'A' && tag.href && e.button === 0) {
        // it's a left-click on an anchor. Lets navigate!
        if (tag.origin === window.location.origin) {
            // prevent the page from navigating

            e.preventDefault();

            // it's a link within the site, HURRAY!
            oldPath = window.location;
            newPath = tag.href,
            navParentEl = tag.parentElement;

            console.log(navParentEl);

            // Update the URL bar! IMPORTANT!
            // @TODO: MOVE INTO A FUNCTION OR OBJECT
            window.history.pushState(null, '', newPath);
            render(window.location.hash, data, e);
        }
    }
});

// register Handlebars partials
hbs.registerPartial({
    'header': hbs.templates.header,
    'footer': hbs.templates.footer
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
    // On every hash change the render function is called with the new hash.
    render(window.location.hash, data, e);
});

function render(url, data, evt) {
    var temp = url.split('/')[0];

    // Hide current page
    $('.pages').addClass('hidden');

    // remove anchors .active class
    //$('.nav-parent').removeClass('active');

    var map = {
        '': function (data) {
            renderPage('home', data);
        },
        '#home': function (data) {
            renderPage('home', data);
        },
        '#gallery': function (data) {
            renderPage('gallery', data);
        },
        '#about': function (data) {
            renderPage('about', data);
        }
    };

    if (map[temp]) {
        map[temp](data);
    } else {
        renderErrorPage(data);
    }
}

function renderPage(page, data) {
    var tpl = hbs.templates[page](data);
    generateView(tpl, page);
}

function renderErrorPage(data) {
    renderPage('error', data);
}

function generateView(tpl, page) {
    var pageId = '#' + page;

    $(pageId).removeClass('hidden');
    $('.container').html(tpl);

    // this works for removing the active class from all li elements
    $('.nav-parent').removeClass('active');

    // add .active class to the new active anchor element
    // does not work
    $(navParentEl).addClass('active');

}

})(jQuery, Handlebars);
```

My navigation HTML:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-parent active"><a href="#home" class="links">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-parent"><a href="#gallery" class="links">Gallery</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-parent"><a href="#about" class="links">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="nav-parent"><a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h3 class="text-muted">{{ projectName }}</h3>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:** Got it working after some tips. I needed to re-think my `generateView()` function. Here's the final code for that function:

```
function generateView(tpl, page) {
    var pageId = '#' + page;

    // remove hidden class from content to be shown
    $(pageId).removeClass('hidden');
    // add the template to the html
    $('.container').html(tpl);
    // move the active class from the former active link
    $('.nav-parent').removeClass('active');

    // get the current hash of the location
    var newHash = window.location.hash,
        // get all links
        _links = document.querySelectorAll('.links'),
        currentActiveLink = '';

    // iterate over the _links object and find the link with href === newHash
    for ( var i = 0; i < _links.length; i++ ) {
        if ( _links[i].getAttribute('href') === newHash ) {
            // store the link with href == newHash 
            // inside the currentActiveLink variable
            currentActiveLink = _links[i];
        }
    }

    // add active class to current active link
    currentActiveLink.parentElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You know the statement which adds the `active` class is commented out right?

Comment: Yes @Andy, It didn't seem to matter. The DOM doesn't update where the li element with class `active` should loose the `active` class so I didn't bother uncommenting the statement which adds the active class to the newly navigated page link since 1) it didn't work, and 2) I was trying to solve the first part of the problem first which is to make the DOM update so that the active class gets removed from the current active link before updating the page. Thank you.

Comment: But you're removing the class before you render the new template, does the header partial contain the navigation HTML? Do you get different results if you remove the `active` class after `$('.container').html(tpl);` in the `generateView` function?

Comment: @Andy, affirmative - The active state does get removed when I call removeClass() after the `$('.container').html(tpl);`. But then I'm supposed to have the new active link stored in the variable `navParentEl` and I call `$(navParentEl).addClass('active');` after the remove method but DOM does not update, although doing `console.log(navParentEl);` does show an updated class list for the supposedly active link.

Comment: It looks like `navParentEl` is undefined in the generateView function. Just seen your edit, glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

isnt it possible that you redraw your navigation? didnt really go through your code but it took me a looong time to discover that in my SPI. I changed some params, but I also ajax-loaded those elements wit default serverside properties...
EDIT: yea I can see that happening in your app

Comment: That makes allot of sense. But the problem is that inheritance in Handlebars is not like I want it to be. According to documentation inheritance in Handlebars is done by including partials and so, I include the same partials (header and footer) on each handlebars page. It would be nice to find a way to have a main template and dynamically update the main content, rather then doing it like I've done here, including the header and footer partials in each handlebars file. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I've used mustache and it was painful. If something was dynamic, I had to redraw it manually and had to make sure that I initialize it to current state, so templates were written in this fassion: <li class="{{#active}}active{{/active}}"> and when my array of menu items was updated, one item was "active" so when I rerendered it, it worked.